# Cannot query across many to many relations NestJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm, nest

I'am trying updated data but I get error like in title. My data have many to many relations like bellow:

Category entity:

```
  @ManyToMany(() => Product, (product: Product) => product.categories)
```

public products: Product[];

Product Entity:

```
  @ManyToMany(() => Category, (category: Category) => category.products)
```

@JoinTable()
public categories: Category[];

To be more precise I want to update Product, who contain category, I want to change category in product:

function to update

```
  async updateProduct(id: string, product: UpdateProductDto) {
try {
  await this.productRepository.update(id, product);
  await this.macroRepository.update(product.macro.id, product.macro);
  const updatedProduct = await this.productRepository.findOne(id);

  if (updatedProduct) {
    return updatedProduct;
  }

  return Promise.reject(new ProductNotFoundException(id));
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
  throw new ServerErrorException();
}
```

}

Do I miss something?

If you want to more info I put my code to: [github repo](https://github.com/radoam/just-proteins-api)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolve this problem by changing `update` method to `save`